# Bounded linear operator with supremum norm.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Given $X=(C[0,1],\Vert\cdot \Vert_\infty)$ and let $y\in X$ be fixed. Now we let $K : X \to X$ be the operator defined as below. Prove that K is a bounded linear operator
and calculate $\Vert K \Vert$.
\begin{equation*}
  K : x\mapsto \frac{xy}{1+t^2}
 \end{equation*}

My Attempt:

\begin{align*}
  \Vert Kx \Vert_\infty &= \sup\left\{\left|\frac{xy}{1+t^2}\right|\right\} \\
         &\leq \sup\left\{\vert x \vert \cdot \frac{\vert y \vert}{1+t^2}\right\} \\
         &= \Vert x \Vert_\infty\cdot\sup\left\{\frac{\vert y \vert}{1+t^2}\right\}
 \end{align*}

I could not figure out what is $\Vert K \Vert$.

Comment: Take $x\equiv 1.$

Comment: Okay eventually I will get $\Vert K \Vert = \sup\left\{\frac{\vert y \vert}{1+t^2}\right\}$

Comment: Since $t \in [0,1]$ you can figure out the value of $K$ in terms of $|y|$.